# what is "Site rename operation extendend storage" feature in SharePoint Online sites

Tags: sharepoint-online, features

I couldnt find any documentation on "**Site rename operation extendend storage**" site collection scoped feature. Can any one share the details if you happen to know.

Answer (score 0):

I searched online and could not find anything about this feature. It should be a new feature in SharePoint Online. I also try to activate it, however, there is nothing changed.

Maybe you need to wait for the official documents.

Or, you can create a new service request about this issue in Admin Center->Support. More Professional will assist you with this feature.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this feature will be used to rename the site (with o365 groups in sponline we have lost ability to rename the site, you need to create a new one and migrate the content, while in SPon prem you can just run cmdlet to rename the site)

I only could find that this feature is creating a hidden list in SPO:

[image: Screenshot from SPO Client Browser]

[image]